# Dropdown menu children shown on parent selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi I want to show a custom taxonomy dropdown based on a parents taxonomy selection, i found this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328990/display-sub-taxonomies-based-on-selected-parent-taxonomy but it is for users and am unable to get it to populate the childrens dropdown based on the parents selection.

Here is what i tried:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'loadlocations', 'hide_empty' => false ));
$parents = array();
echo '<select name="parent_category" id="parent_category">';
echo '<option value="pleaseselect">please select</option>';
foreach ($terms as $item) {
    if($item->parent===0){
        $parents[] = $item;
        echo '<option value="'.$item->term_id.'">'.$item->name.'</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
//print_r($parents); //Show all the parent objects


echo "<div id='child_category_row'>";

$parent = $_POST['parent'];
$terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'loadlocations', 'hide_empty' => false ));
$children = array();
echo '<select name="child_category" id="child_category">';
echo '<option value="pleaseselect">please select</option>';
foreach ($terms as $item) {
    if($item->parent === $parent){
        $children[] = $item;
        echo '<option value="'.$children->term_id.'">'.$children->name.'</option>';
    }
}
//print_r($children); //show all children objects
echo '</select>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

i tried both jquery examples in that link but was unable to edit it to get it to work.

Comment: Did you try with hardcoded option values instead of dynamic?

Comment: yes but maybe im missing some more php as i saw with the example i found they had some php in their functions file which i tried to put but that didn't change anything, and i tried the jquery they used.

Comment: Share the working demo link here